# mongoid creating different collections on mongohq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongohq

I have this model

```
class Noticia
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Slug

  belongs_to :user

  field :titulo, :type => String
  field :conteudo, :type => String
  field :tags, :type => Array

  index :tags
  slug :titulo
end
```

with this environment

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'inscricao', 'inscricoes'
  inflect.irregular 'noticia', 'noticias'
  inflect.irregular 'central', 'centrais'
end
```

when I create a 'noticia' locally, it creates on collection 'noticia'. But when I create a 'noticia' on heroku, it appears on a collection called 'noticias'. plus, the `notcias` collection didn't have a `tags` field, that is really important to my app, to perform searchs on `noticia`

Any ideas?

Comment: anyone? tried remove the line `inflect.irregular 'noticia', 'noticias'`, but didn't worked too

Comment: I gave it a try, and things work for me.  I did notice that the inflect did not take effect if I put it after Application.initialize! in environment.rb.  Where did you put it?  Can you reproduce your problem locally, with noticia --> noticia?  I did not try on heroku yet, as I was able to get noticia --> noticias to inflect locally.  Test code is available on request.

Comment: yup, you were right. put right before `Application.initialize!` did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to hear that putting the inflect calls before Application.initialize! fixed your problem.